# unreadable axis on log axis on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm plotting data from a csv file in tikz, using a semi-log figure.
Here is the csv file :

```
col1,col2
20,33.45548100142213
40,33.45548098124385
70,33.11568704357836
100,32.77583220127542
320,3.0281711020398632e+01
```

and here is the TeX source :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}
        \addplot table[x=col1, y=col2, col sep=comma] {dat.csv};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

the result given looks like that

[image: result]

but the values displayed on the xaxis are not really understandable (10^1.5 for instance). Is there a way to label it with « usual » values (10, 10^2, etc...) ?

**EDIT :**
For instance, using these data

```
col1,col2
8,33.77839299358055
10,33.45548098124431
12,33.144872130372164
15,32.70061685445444
100,26.00021051080506
```

The result is « fine » : we have *10^i* (with *i* an integer) on the axis, and we have small lines for the intermediary values (I have not change anything in the option of `addplot` to get this result, I have only taken another set of data)

[image: another result]

Comment: Of the "usual values", only 10^2 is in the range of your data. Would you prefer to only have that on the x-axis?

Comment: I've edited the post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\begin{filecontents}{dat.csv}
col1,col2
20,33.45548100142213
40,33.45548098124385
70,33.11568704357836
100,32.77583220127542
320,3.0281711020398632e+01
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[xmin=10, xmax=1000]
\addplot table[x=col1, y=col2, col sep=comma] {dat.csv};
\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with log x-axis]

Using `\begin{semilogxaxis}[xtick=100]` creates a graph without "voids"

[image: Graph with only one x-axis tick]

Comment: that works well, thanks. The only problem is that it creates voids on the left and right part, but I think that it will be unavoidable

Comment: @Thomas: See edit for solution without "voids". Remember to accept answer.